# How to fix run-time error 2185 in MS Access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Good day,
I am experiencing a run-time error 2185. There does not seem any errors with the code as it works with other entries in the db. I am only having this problem with a few of the entries and do not understand why. Below is my code I would appreciate any help.

```vb
Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim ColCount As Long
    Dim Message As String
    Dim EncodedMsg As String
     
    Message = DrivingInitialSurname.Text
    Message = Message & vbCrLf & Text93.Text
    Message = Message & vbCrLf & DrivingDateIssue.Text
    Message = Message & vbCrLf & Text161.Text
    
    ' encode string using QRCode
    Call QRCodeEncode(Message, Version, Level, Mask)
    
    ' how many rows?
    RowCount = QRCodeGetRows()
    
    ' how many characters in one row?
    ColCount = QRCodeGetCols()
    
    EncodedMsg = vbCrLf
    For I = 1 To RowCount
        For J = 1 To ColCount
            EncodedMsg = EncodedMsg & Chr(QRCodeGetCharAt(I - 1, J - 1))
        Next J
        EncodedMsg = EncodedMsg & vbCrLf
    Next I
    
    txtQRCode.Value = EncodedMsg
End Sub
```

Comment: What is error 2185 (Some of us haven't memorised all of the error codes), and which line does the error occur on?

Comment: On the debug  Message = DrivingInitialSurname.Text
you can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has a focus

Comment: Use `?AccessError(2185)` in the immediate window to retrieve a detailled error description: `You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus.@Try one of the following: * Move the focus to the control before you reference the property. In Visual Basic code, use the SetFocus method. In a macro, use the GoToControl action. * Reference or set the property from a macro or event procedure that runs when the GotFocus event for the control occurs.@@2@1@6215@1`

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` property only works for a control having focus. So try:

```vb
    Message = Me!DrivingInitialSurname.Value
    Message = Message & vbCrLf & Me!Text93.Value
    Message = Message & vbCrLf & Me!DrivingDateIssue.Value
    Message = Message & vbCrLf & Me!Text161.Value
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am still getting the same error after the change.